# BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74 : Method controller does not exist

Tags: laravel-5

I'm getting little bit issue when I follow Route Controller.

Web.php Code:

```
{"
Route::controller('/admin','adminController');
"}
```

adminController.php Code:

```
{"
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
class adminController extends Controller{
public function getDashboard(){
echo " Get Dashborad Method ";
}}
"}
```

When I hit `http://localhost:8000/admin/dashboard`
an error:

> Display ("BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74 : Method controller does not exist.")

Here is SnapShot:

[image: http://take.ms/3NqA4]

Please take a look and let me know what is wrong with code.

Comment: Please show the code in Macroable.php line 74 as suggested by the error message. Looks like whatever it's trying to call doesn't exist.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Faced the same problem recently. Laravel 5.3 does not support Route::controller() method. You need to change it to Route::get(). 
Please check how to use it here https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#basic-routing.

Answer (score 11):

Please also make sure you don't use any namespace inside your routes file.

E.g. If by mistake your IDE add's

```
use Illuminate\Routing\Route;
```

It could result in the same error mentioned above. Your route file (web.php or api.php) should not  use the *Illuminate\Routing\Route* class.

**EDIT:**
Tested on Laravel 5.5

Comment: Holy shit!!! You saved my day. There is no any "use" in Route file. Thanks bro... :)

Comment: Saved my day. Thank you

Comment: having the same issue. :/

Answer (score 3):

I got this error while running artisan command. Finally, I solve by removing the,

> use Illuminate\Routing\Route

in web.php file.

Answer (score 0):

i have just solved this problem i was using

```
$table->int('TeachingGroup_id');
```

where i should use the full integer Not int only by solving this now migration done S